# Is it safe to expose the Elasticsearch Search API directly through your application's API?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am developing an AngularJS app with a Java/Spring Boot API. It uses Spring Data Elasticsearch to provide access to Elasticsearch's Search API for searching. Here is an example:

```
Page<Address> page = addressSearchRepository.search(simpleQueryStringQuery(query), pageable);
```

The variable `query` is a user's search string. `pageable` is an object that specifies page number, page size, and sorting. I can use `QueryBuilders` to build other Elasticsearch queries and expose them as different API endpoints.

Another option is to use `QueryBuilders.wrapperQuery` and send Elasticsearch queries directly from JavaScript. Here is an example where `jsonQuery` is a string containing a full Elasticsearch query:

```
Page<Address> page = addressSearchRepository.search(wrapperQuery(jsonQuery), pageable);
```

This would be a secure endpoint that only authenticated users can access. This seems to be equivalent to exposing an Elasticsearch index's Search API directly. Assuming that any data in the index is safe to show the user, would this be a security risk?

In my research so far I've found that it may be possible to crash Elasticsearch using a query, but it isn't that big of a problem in newer versions: https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-crash-elasticsearch#arbitrary-large-size-parameter

Maybe limiting the page size or using the scan and scroll API when the page size is very large would mitigate this.

I know that script fields should be avoided at all costs, but they are disabled by default (as of v1.4.3).

Comment: Elastic's team is trying to implement other circuit breakers and to add default limits to certain types of queries and aggregations. But if your aim is for your users not to crash ES, while they have full access to all queries, I think there are ways to crash it. I wouldn't expose ES and le my users do whatever they want with whatever queries they create. There are ways, especially with aggregations where one can cripple ES or even cripple the cluster.

Comment: Looks like the premise of my question is wrong. The query sent by the client is wrapped like this, which fails with the error `No query registered for [aggregations]`: `{"from":0,"size":20,"query":{"wrapper":{"query":"json query here"}}}`. I haven't been able to run an aggregation so far.

Comment: Is there a place (aside from the source I linked to in the question) where I can read about other methods of cashing ES using search queries so I can guard against them?

Comment: I don't understand from that `wrapper` pseudo-query you provided what is the actual input from the user and what is the actual wrapper in your code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can still crash Elasticsearch if you know how to do it. For example, if you start building a 10 deep nested aggregations, you might very well go and take a break. It will either take a lot of time, or be very expensive, use a lot of memory, make the JVM do a lot of garbage collection (which basically freezes all other threads running in the JVM), reclaim back small amounts of memory. It can make the cluster unresponsive in this way.

I'm not saying that whatever aggregations you take and create a 10 deep nested aggregations you'll cripple the cluster, but under normal circumstances a cluster built for a certain SLA and deal with a certain amount of data, given some heavy aggregations (for example `terms` on `analyzed` string fields), will be very highly computational for the nodes.

Maybe the nodes will not run out of memory, but the nodes will barely be responsive.

Elastic's team is trying to [implement other circuit breakers](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/19394) and to [add default limits to certain types of queries and aggregations](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/11511) (a huge task). But if your aim is for your users not to crash ES, while they have full access to all queries, I think there are ways to crash it. I, personally, wouldn't expose ES and let my users do whatever they want with whatever queries they create.

Depending on how your `wrapper` is configured, I'd only allow my users certain types of queries/aggregations and for those I'd impose some limits (applicable for those queries/aggs that **accept** limits).